# extract details from this string

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

i was trying to extract caption,url and image link from this source and i have used following preg_match and it works but it gives only for one set but i want for all set .for example here it is three set so i want to get details of all three. i know in anchor we can use getattribute('title') alt an etc but how to use here .

```
 <urlset>

  <url><loc>/1366x768/citroen-ds-cabrio-auto-car-wallshark-com-228615.html</loc><image:image><image:loc>s/1366x768/citroen-ds/228615/citroen-ds-cabrio-auto-car-wallshark-com-228615.jpg</image:loc><image:caption>Citroen Ds Cabrio Auto Car Wallshark Com  Walpapers</image:caption></image:image></url>

 <url><loc>/1366x768/citroen-ds-cars-citro-n-cabrio-213157.html</loc><image:image><image:loc>s/1366x768/citroen-ds/213157/citroen-ds-cars-citro-n-cabrio-213157.jpg</image:loc><image:caption>Citroen Ds Cars Citro N Cabrio  Walpapers</image:caption></image:image></url>

  <url><loc>/1366x768/citroen-ds-citro-n-pictures-95569.html</loc><image:image><image:loc>s/1366x768/citroen-ds/95569/citroen-ds-citro-n-pictures-95569.jpg</image:loc><image:caption>Citroen Ds Citro N Pictures  Walpapers</image:caption></image:image></url>
  </urlset>
```

here is my preg match for caption and image link which works fine but only for one

```
            preg_match("/\<image:caption\>(.*)\<\/image:caption\>/",$str,$title);

            preg_match("/\<image:loc\>(.*)\<\/image:loc\>/",$str,$title);
```

how to make it work to extract all details

Comment: use an xml parser instead http://www.php.net/xml or http://www.php.net/simplexml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`? A better approach:

```
   preg_match_all("/<image:caption>.*?<\/image:caption>|<image:loc>.*?<\/image:loc>|<loc>.*?<\/loc>/", $text, $results);
   $arr = array_chunk(array_map('strip_tags', $results[0]), 3);
   print_r($arr);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /1366x768/citroen-ds-cabrio-auto-car-wallshark-com-228615.html
            [1] => s/1366x768/citroen-ds/228615/citroen-ds-cabrio-auto-car-wallshark-com-228615.jpg
            [2] => Citroen Ds Cabrio Auto Car Wallshark Com  Walpapers
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => /1366x768/citroen-ds-cars-citro-n-cabrio-213157.html
            [1] => s/1366x768/citroen-ds/213157/citroen-ds-cars-citro-n-cabrio-213157.jpg
            [2] => Citroen Ds Cars Citro N Cabrio  Walpapers
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => /1366x768/citroen-ds-citro-n-pictures-95569.html
            [1] => s/1366x768/citroen-ds/95569/citroen-ds-citro-n-pictures-95569.jpg
            [2] => Citroen Ds Citro N Pictures  Walpapers
        )

)
```

Comment: it will give caption and image url as one url but i want both to be seperate so that i canstore them in database

Comment: @user3026718 you'll have 9 match and that's correct. you can check  live demo here: http://regex101.com/r/mN0xJ8

Comment: agree but i dont want to insert these 9 values in 9 row .i want to insert in three columns and three row so 9 values.but in ur case all will go to new row

Comment: i have done this but the browser is crashing for 1000 values and one more thing how can i get the value dynamically in array_chunk. i dont want to give manuaaly something like 400,500 it should be taken automatically again i have to run one more loop?  here is what i have done which is crashing and in j value i tried less than 3 but in that case output is truncated to 3 set only ---------------- code starts here           $arr = array_chunk(array_map('strip_tags', $results[0]), 1000);for($i=0;$i < 1000;$i++){
 for($j=0;$j < 1000;$j++){
 
 
$output=$arr[$i][$j]. '</br>';


echo $output;
 }
 
 }

Comment: @user3026718 you iterate over that array with array_map or array_walk and do whatever you want. 1000 values are not much actually!

Comment: i  am trying to do this for each <url> tags extract the 3 values, and there are a column for loc, a column for image:loc and a column for caption in database